# retrieve same data exists in two different tables with same column structure

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables with identical column layout but containing different data entered by year. I need to run a query that will find all the entries across both tables where the data in one of the specified columns is the same, such as:

`id | serialNo | enteredBy | entryDate| processedBy | processDate ...`

rows containing the same serial number (referencing the same item) in both tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like:

`SELECT * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON (t1.serialNum = t2.serialNum)`